# How to enable italics on React component attributes in vim?

Tags: reactjs, vim, syntax-highlighting

I am using iTerm2 with italics enabled, and I have the following in my vimrc:

```
Plugin 'pangloss/vim-javascript' "
Plugin 'mxw/vim-jsx' "

set background=dark
colorscheme one
let g:one_allow_italics = 1

hi htmlArg gui=italic
hi htmlArg cterm=italic
hi Comment gui=italic
hi Comment cterm=italic
hi Type    gui=italic
hi Type    cterm=italic
```

Standard html attributes and comments are currently rendering in italics, but React component attributes are not. Has anyone got this working?

Comment: I would put the `let g:one_allow_italics = 1` _above_ the `:colorscheme one` (as it presumably configures the colorscheme), but if you see some kind of italics, that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using a theme that did not enable italics for React components, switching themes fixed my issue.